# AngularJS module and controller

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have written two different angular js codes.

One contains module and controller. This looks like below and works well on my html file!

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('demo', [])
    .controller('repeatController', repeatController);

  function repeatController($scope) {

  }
})();
```

I, however, have these two js files like below. One only contains module, and the other has controller in it. I tested angularjs simply by using {{}} but it does not work on the html file. {{3+1}} appears to be {{3+1}} not 4.

```
(function(){

    angular
        .module('demo', [])

})(a);
```

and

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('demo')
        .controller("repeatController", repeatController);

        function repeatController(){

        }

})();
```

Can anyone fix the bottom one?

Comment: The question lacks [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and cannot get a quality answer. The most obvious explanation is that you didn't look into the console - you will see errors there, because it won't fail silently in a situation like that.

Answer (score 1):

Change first file like this E.g. app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('demo', []);
```

And second:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
    angular
        .module('demo')
        .controller("repeatController", repeatController);

        function repeatController(){

        }

})();
```

Check this style guide:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: Now "use strict" is global, not a good idea if any other script that follows in page isn't compliant. Only problem ws using 2 module declarations for same module